# New Age column not getting created in a dataframe python

Tags: python, date, datetime

I have to create a new column 'Age' in dataframe house which would be the difference of Int type 'YearBuilt' column and Current Year.
Below is the code that i use .Although it executes, but the column 'Age' is not getting created in house df.
What am i doing wrong? Can someone suggest?

**Code:**

```
from datetime import date

today=date.today()

house.Age=today.year-house.YearBuilt
```

Comment: since you seem to use `pandas` anyway, you could change your last line to `house.Age = pd.Timestamp('now').year - house.YearBuilt`

Answer (score 0):

This happens because Pandas doesn't allow columns to be created via a new attribute name - [See this link](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#attribute-access)

Try doing something like :

```
house['age'] = today.year - house['YearBuilt']
```